# Get value of object inside a for loop with dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm trying to get a value of property (or more) that user provides inside a for loop.

---

#### OBJECT:

```
RULES: { 
  "required": /.+/, 
  "numeric": /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/ 
}
```

#### FOR LOOP:

```
$("input").keyup(function() {

  var inputVal = $(this).val();
  var rules = $(this).data('rules').split(" ");

  for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {

     console.log(rules[i]); // OK - return "required" and "numeric"
     console.log(RULES.required); // OK - return "/.+/"

     console.log(RULES.rules[i]); // NOT OK

  };

});
```

#### MARKUP

```
<input data-rules="required numeric" type="text">
```

The problem is that it provokes an error: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

So how can I look for the value of "rule[i]" and not "rule[i]" itself?
Why does not translate by itself?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Huh? You don't have a `RULES.rules`, so of course it's not ok. If you are going to use numerical indexes, you really ought to use an array.

Comment: TY @Matt,
Also, rules and RULES are not the same

Comment: @Cerbrus can you review this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing:

```
RULES.rules[i]
```

you should do:

```
RULES[rules[i]]
```

when you do the first one, Javascript first looks for a `rules` property on the `RULES` object (but this property doesn't exist) then it tries to access element `0` of the `rules` property, which doesn't exist... hence you get *"Cannot read property '0' of undefined"* error

in the case where you want to access the property of an object using a variable for the name you cannot use dot notation any more and must use the square brackets